# How to set redirect_uri parameter on OpenIdConnectOptions for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm trying to connect an ASP.NET application to Salesforce using OpenId, Currently this is my connecting code so far. I think I got everything except the redirect_uri parameter, which has to match the value on the other end exactly.

```cs
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            x.CookieName = "MyApp";
            x.CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always;
            x.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
   
        });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            x.Authority = "https://login.salesforce.com";
            x.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID_HERE";
            x.ResponseType = "code";
            x.AuthenticationScheme = "oidc";
            x.CallbackPath = new PathString("/services/oauth2/success");
            //x.RedirectUri = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success";
            x.Scope.Add("openid");
            x.Scope.Add("profile");
            x.Scope.Add("email");                
        });
```

But RedirectUri isn't a valid parameter to pass. What is the right way to set it?

Comment: For OIDC add `x.SignInScheme = "Cookies"` and remove `x.AutomaticAuthenticate`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`redirect_uri` is automatically computed for you using the scheme, host, port and path extracted from the current request and the `CallbackPath` you specify.

`x.RedirectUri = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success"` looks highly suspicious (unless you work for Salesforce): don't forget it's the callback URL the user agent will be redirected to when the authentication flow completes, not the authorization endpoint of your identity provider.

So in your case, the user will be redirected to `http(s)://yourdomain.com/services/oauth2/success`. Is it the address you registered in your Salesforce options?

Comment: Works really well with reverse proxy!

Comment: If the redirect_uri is automatically calculated, how do you deal with an app that's served at `https://some.friendly.url.com` but it's hosted on Azure at `https://some-ugly-hidden-url.not.to.be.used`? Can you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084004/how-to-get-azure-oidc-to-respect-my-redirect-uri), please?

Answer (score 44):

You need to set an event listen for the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`

in your case:

```
x.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
{
    n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = <Redirect URI string>;
    await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: As always some manual work is required when comes to production. At least they made extension points in form of events.

Comment: Great solution, saved the day today. Thank you!

Comment: FYI in .NET 4.6, and all versions of .NET Core, you can use `Task.CompletedTask` instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** App services have a default domain name of *.azurewebsites.net (say contoso.azurewebsites.net) which is different from the application gateway’s domain name (say contoso.com). Since the original request from the client has application gateway’s domain name contoso.com as the host name, the application gateway changes the hostname to contoso.azurewebsites.net, so that the app service in the backend can route it to the correct endpoint. But when the app service sends a redirection response, it uses the same hostname in the location header of its response as the one in the request it receives from the application gateway. Therefore, when the app service performs a redirection to its relative path (redirect from /path1 to /path2), the client will make the request directly to contoso.azurewebsites.net/path2, instead of going through the application gateway (contoso.com/path2). This will bypass the application gateway which is not desirable.

**Solution:** This issue can be resolved by setting the hostname in the location header to the application gateway’s domain name.

For more details you can check this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rewrite-http-headers-with-azure-application-gateway/