# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC AddOpenIDConnect with IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated. I have wasted days on the matter.

Authenticating an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app with IdentityServer3 is causing a runtime error. The Identity server is returning an error

> The client application is not known or is not authorized

instead of a login screen. We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and an ASP.NET Core API that works fine with the identity server.

My approach has been to rewrite the ASP.NET MVC 5 code in .NET Core. I have done the best that I can without being able to find any documentation on how to do such a translation. Please see my code snippets below for details.

Working ASP.NET MVC 5 code:

```
    //***
    //commented all code that was not needed to get login screen to show up
    //***
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Name;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 300, 0),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });

        var clientBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ClientBaseUrlKey];
        var identityServerBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[IdentityServerBaseUrlKey];

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = identityServerBaseUrl,
            ClientId = WebSettings.ClientId,
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            UseTokenLifetime = false//,
            RedirectUri = $"{clientBaseUrl}/",
            //PostLogoutRedirectUri = clientBaseUrl,
            //Scope = "openid profile roles admin_certpay",

            //Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            //{
```

...removed for brevity...
            });
        }

Problematic ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC code:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
        }).AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Authority = "http://localhost/identity/";
            o.ClientId = "actual value used here";
            o.ResponseType = "code id_token token"; 
            o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.UseTokenLifetime = false;
            //start - not sure what RedirectUri is, but PostLogoutRedirectUri doesn't matter
            o.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost/CertPay.Admin/";
            o.ReturnUrlParameter = "http://localhost/CertPay.Admin/";
            //end - not sure what RedirectUri is, but PostLogoutRedirectUri doesn't matter
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; //fix to runtime error
        });

        //Played with Core API fix for the hell of it.
        //.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
        //{
        //    o.Authority = "http://localhost/identity/";
        //    //o.ApiName = "actual value here";
        //    o.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;
        //    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        //});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Pedro The Kid on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976870/how-to-set-redirect-uri-parameter-on-openidconnectoptions-for-asp-net-core) solved my problem.  The removal of the RedirectUri attribute can be compensated for by adding an event listener.  For your convenience, an excerpt from Pedro's follows:

```
x.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
{
    n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = <Redirect URI string>;
    await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

**Edit:** The above solution actual caused an endless loop of the login page loading a bunch of times.  The following solution did not cause that problem:

```
o.CallbackPath = "/home/index/";
```