# Navigate to a specific razor pages after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, razor-pages

I have created an app using RazorPages where users need to login in order to access it should login. For authentication, I am using an external IdentityProvider (IdentityServer

On the Login page, the login button executes the following code:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostLogin()
{
    return Challenge();
}
```

In the StartUp.cs, I set the following parameters:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddHttpClient();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
     {
            options.Authority = StringResources.Authority;
            options.ClientId = StringResources.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = StringResources.ClientSecret;
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.ResponseMode = "query";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
     });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ......
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    .....
}
```

After the user clicks on the login button, the external Identity Provider is opened. If the user logged in successfully, the default CallbackPath (/signin-oidc?) is called. However, I don't understand how I can redirect the authenticated user to the main page of my app.

I wanted to set CallbackPath directly on the Razor Page handler, but setting it like this:

```cs
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Home?handler=callback");
```

the char `?` is encoded and therefore the Identity Provider returns an invalid uri.

How do I redirect the user back to a specific page after the authentication was successfull?

Comment: Callback path is for exchanging `code` for a `token` when the user returns from the OIDC provider. You should set the redirect uri to an action when issuing a challenge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set redirect\_uri parameter on OpenIdConnectOptions for ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976870/how-to-set-redirect-uri-parameter-on-openidconnectoptions-for-asp-net-core)

Comment: @maghazade That's not it. `return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/callback/uri" })`

Answer (score 1):

**EVENTS**

There are a couple of places where you can customize behaviour of your server side web app via the [Events property of the options object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

- Set an HTTP only cookie with the current app location in `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`
- Restore that location from the cookie in `OnTokenValidated`, then expire the cookie

There may even be an option for this to happen automatically - some tech stacks support this.

**DEEP LINKING**

A user should be able to bookmark a location like this, then open it in a new browser session (eg an incognito page):

- https://myapp/photos/789

The user is not logged in yet so will redirect to sign in, then return to the correct location.

**SINGLE PAGE APPS**

How the app manages its location is easier to understand for a single page app - as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L106), where the location is instead stored in session storage.