# ASP.NET core OIDC: override the redirect url when behind reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, openid-connect, openid, url-rewrite-module

I have an SPA with a ASP.NET core backend that protects the SPA from unauthorized users. The backend is using OpenID connect with authorization code flow (pkce), along with an Identity Provider. The backend is hosted in IIS on own server (server1). Users can't access this server directly. To solve this there is another server (server2) with IIS url rewrite rules that acts as a reverse proxy. There is a simple inbound rewrite rule: `https://server2/myApp` -> `https://server1:8081`

This is the flow when accessing the SPA as unauthorized:

1. Redirection to login page of IdP
2. Redirection to authorize endpoint of IdP
3. Redirection to callback endpoint of backend.

The problem is the last step in when the redirection (or callback) is made, which is to `https://server1:8081/signin-oidc`. End-users can't access this url.

Is it possible to fix this in the ASP.NET core backend in some way? I can't find a way to change this entire callback url, just only the path.
Or is the only way to fix it in the revere proxy? The callback step doesn't seem to be a ordinary redirect (status 302) and I don't how the request is initiated. I can't figure it out how to setup a rule for handling it in the proxy.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, are you trying to set up a Reverse Proxy? If yes, you can refer to this link: [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing), If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Ran into a similar issue. One solution is to react to the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event in your application code and change the effective redirect url (the one in the `ProtocolMessage`) as needed. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976870/how-to-set-redirect-uri-parameter-on-openidconnectoptions-for-asp-net-core